# How to bring into view all TreeViewItems of expanded TreeViewItem

Tags: wpf, treeview

On my `Window` I have `TreeView`. `TreeView.ItemsSource` is binded to my data (hierarchical data structure). When I expand some `TreeViewItem` that is on the bottom of the current scrollbar position, my subitems are hidden and I have to scroll to see them. Is there any way to bring all subitems of expanded item into view?

I have tried this, but didn't work:

```
public void TreeViewItem_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewItem tvi = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
    if (tvi != null)
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("TreeNode '{0}' was expanded", tvi.Header);
        tvi.BringIntoView();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, select the last sub-item and bring it into view when an item is expanded. If it has no subitems, bring the item itself into view.

The tricky part is, subitems are not necessarily available when the event is executed, so I propose you check the `ItemContainerGenerator.Status` and if it's not yet done, subscribe to the `ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged` event.

The following code is only tested with static items, if it's making problem for dynamic data sources, I may have to re-check a few details.

```
void TreeViewItem_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewItem tvi = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
    if (tvi != null)
    {
        if (tvi.HasItems)
        {
            if (tvi.ItemContainerGenerator.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
            {
                BringLastItemIntoView(tvi.ItemContainerGenerator);
            }
            else
            {
                tvi.ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged += ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            tvi.BringIntoView();
        }
    }
}

void ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var s = sender as ItemContainerGenerator;
    if (s.Status == GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
    {
        BringLastItemIntoView(s);
        s.StatusChanged -= ItemContainerGenerator_StatusChanged;
    }
}

void BringLastItemIntoView(ItemContainerGenerator generator)
{
    var tvi = generator.ContainerFromItem(generator.Items.LastOrDefault()) as TreeViewItem;
    if (tvi != null)
    {
        tvi.BringIntoView();
    }
}
```